# CSS-only sticky header with background color transition when scrolling but no JS

Tags: html, css, sass, user-experience

I want to create the sticky header effect that you can see here on this [JekyNewAge theme](https://jekynewage.github.io/) page, where the header menu is transparent as long as it hovers over the hero section, but will transition to a white background as soon as you scroll past this region.

The code is for a "No-JS" site, so solution must be pure CSS and no javascript.

Have been experimenting with various `position: sticky` setups and older ways to achieve stickiness, but without luck. There are many examples on the web on how to do this, but none so far that I found which does it without javascript. There's always some jQuery or other code snippet involved.

Note: My CSS is generated from SaSS document, so examples using this would be great too.

Maybe this is not possible.. I would very much appreciate your input!

Comment: Are you added jquery for sticky header ?

Comment: Is your hero section full width?

Comment: Yes, it is full width, and I have no javascript at all in my entire site. Adding JS is no option.

Comment: The header transition effect can't be done without js, as far as I know, as css doesn't know about the scroll position. The best you could do is duplicate the header markup and make it appear in some tricky way with the scrolling, but won't be the same

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid that was the case. Only transition you get with `sticky` is where it disappears when scrolling past the region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought about it a little. I still don't think you can do the transition as in the example with pure css, but this is the kind of trick I was thinking about, which does have a transparent header over the hero that gets a solid background after it. Maybe it helps:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.hero {
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.header-bg {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
}
.content {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 2rem;
  min-height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<div class="hero">HERO</div>
<div class="header-bg">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This works with only slight concessions to the original example. But I take that if this means I can stick with my "No-JS" approach :)

Answer (score 0):

you just need add   z-index: 1; in class selector

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).